# Paypal Subscriptions - Getting users to continue to success/failure URLs

Tags: paypal

I have a private, paid-user-only service and I'm using Paypal Subscriptions as my payment gateway. It has been properly set-up (or I believe it has) with custom URLs defined for successful payments or cancellations.

The success URL is what "activates" the user's account. However I find that users who make the payment don't follow thru by continuing to the successful payment URL. For users who cancel, I don't have a problem.

But for those who make the payment but will not follow thru, I end up having to manually activate their accounts.

What I need is Paypal to "ping" my activation / success URL when the payment is complete. I'm sure I've seen websites do this properly with Paypal. I wonder how it is done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use "IPN", it's a paypal service that send info about activation/deactivation to a URL on your site and is well documented at https://www.paypal.com/ipn

Comment: Nir is right, you use paypal IPN for this.  You can create an IPN script in almost any language.  PHP is easiest because of the number of solutions in this.  If you need a script in classic asp let me know, i have it.  Essentially the IPN (instant payment notification) is data paypal sends to your site about transactions.  It will let you know if a subscription has been created, payment failed etc.  See the link below...

Comment: https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro